# Firestore Query by timestemp with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am adding a document to my collection like this.

```
void addToDb() {
collectionReference.add({
  'dateTime': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
});}
```

i am trying to query data after a certain date time like this

```
Firestore.instance
                .collection('items')
                .orderBy('dateTime', descending: true).startAt([{'dateTime' : DateTime.parse('2019-03-13 16:49:42.044')}])
                .snapshots(),
```

When i set descending to true, i get back all the docs.
When i set to false i get back none.
Both are not expected results.

I seen a few on stack saying to convert date time to just milliseconds or unix. but i am using the servertimestamp because i cant trust the client to write the time stamp. Any idea how i can query date time ranges with servertimestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really explain why this works, but this works for me.

```
final startAtTimestamp = Timestamp.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(DateTime.parse('2019-03-13 16:49:42.044').millisecondsSinceEpoch);
Firestore.instance
                .collection('items')
                .orderBy('dateTime', descending: true).startAt([startAtTimestamp])
                .snapshots()
```

Comment: ".orderBy('Timestamp', descending: true)" worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do as follows,

```
Firestore.instance
            .collection("driverListedRides")
            .where("uid", isEqualTo: widget.uid.toString())
            .where("status", isEqualTo: "active")
            .where("date",
                isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:
                    DateTime.now().toString().split(" ")[0].toString())
            .orderBy("date", descending: true)
            .orderBy("time", descending: false)
```